# Why am I getting NaN and How do I get the expected output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I'm a JS newbie. I want to keep track of number of duplicate objects in an array, in another object, so I decided to write a function. For example: consider the below object.

```
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];
```

I want to keep track of number of duplicate object in the above array, so I wrote the below function.

```
function calcDuplicates(fruitObj) {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i of fruitObj) {
    duplicates[`${i.name}`] !== "undefined"
      ? (duplicates[`${i.name}`] += 1)
      : (duplicates[`${i.name}`] = 1);
  }
  return duplicates;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
{orange: NaN, apple: NaN, banana: NaN}
```

(**Expected output**) The output which I want is:

```
{orange: 2, apple: 1, banana: 1}
```

How do I get the expected output? what mistake am I doing?

Comment: But `noOfItems` is undefined? The code should crash with an error `noOfItems is undefined`

Comment: Because `duplicates['${i.name}']` is undefined at first, and when you add `1` to it, it gives you `NaN`, cause `undefined + 1 => NaN`

Comment: `duplicates[\`${i.name}\`]` does the same as `duplicates[i.name]`

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm sorry, while asking the question, I renamed `noOfItems` to `duplicates` and forgot to change it in the return, I've corrected it.

Comment: @AdilBimzagh `duplicates[i.name]` is initialized to `1` on line 8, if undefined

Comment: @JeremyThille the undefined check is incorrect, so it's never inistialised.

Comment: @JeremyThille No it's not. `duplicates[\`${i.name}\`] !== "undefined"` will always be `true` (if there's no `"undefined"` property)

Comment: Yep that's correct, but at least OP thought of initializing it to `1`, and not doing `undefined + 1`. The intention was there :)

Comment: `duplicates[\`${i.name}\`] !== "undefined" ? (duplicates[\`${i.name}\`] += 1) : (duplicates[\`${i.name}\`] = 1)` - that's not how the ternary operator is supposed to be used. `... ? ... : ...` is a set of three expression and not an expression and two statements. That line should be `duplicates[i.name] = (duplicates[i.name] || 0) + 1` (or a plain old `if...else...`

Comment: This was my first question here, I was feeling really shy to ask but asked it anyway and you guys helped me understand my mistake and educated me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need to use string literals for the property name. `i.name` is sufficient.
2. You were checking "undefined" rather than `undefined`. But, really, there's no need to do that. Just check for the existence of the object property.

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];

function calcDuplicates(fruitObj) {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i of fruitObj) {
    duplicates[i.name]
      ? duplicates[i.name] += 1
      : duplicates[i.name] = 1;
  }
  return duplicates;
}

console.log(calcDuplicates(fruits));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is testing against `"undefined"` (the word) instead of `undefined` (an undefined value) :

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];

function calcDuplicates(fruitObj) {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i of fruitObj) {
    duplicates[i.name] !== undefined
      ? (duplicates[i.name] += 1)
      : (duplicates[i.name] = 1);
  }
  return duplicates;
}

console.log( calcDuplicates(fruits) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of string `"undefined"` use the primitive value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined) in the condition:

```
duplicates[`${i.name}`] !== undefined
```

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];

function calcDuplicates(fruitObj) {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i of fruitObj) {
    duplicates[`${i.name}`] !== undefined
      ? (duplicates[`${i.name}`] += 1)
      : (duplicates[`${i.name}`] = 1);
  }
  return duplicates;
}
console.log(calcDuplicates(fruits))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your condition should be tested against `undefined`, not a string containing `'undefined'`.

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];

function calcDuplicates(fruitObj) {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i of fruitObj) {
    duplicates[`${i.name}`] !== undefined
      ? (duplicates[`${i.name}`] += 1)
      : (duplicates[`${i.name}`] = 1);
  }
  return duplicates;
}

console.log( calcDuplicates(fruits) );
```

And this is how I'd write it:

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];

function calcDuplicates(fruitObj) {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i of fruitObj) {
    duplicates[i.name] = (duplicates[i.name] || 0) + 1
  }
  return duplicates;
}

console.log( calcDuplicates(fruits) );
```

Pretty much same thing, using `reduce` and a destructuring `map`:

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];

const calcDuplicates = o => o
  .map(({ name }) => name)
  .reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]: (a[b] || 0) + 1 }), {})

console.log( calcDuplicates(fruits) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove double quotes " from undefined

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];

function calcDuplicates(fruitObj) {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i of fruitObj) {
    duplicates[`${i.name}`] !== undefined
      ? (duplicates[`${i.name}`] += 1)
      : (duplicates[`${i.name}`] = 1);
  }
  return duplicates;
}

console.log( calcDuplicates(fruits) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with `reduce` and object destructuring, as follows:

```js
const fruits = [{name: 'orange'}, {name: 'orange'}, {name: 'apple'}, {name: 'banana'}];


const duplicates = fruits.reduce( (acc,{name}) => {
  if (!acc[name]) acc[name] = 0 ; 
  acc[name]++;
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: Thanks @sivaraj-s for you edit, but that changes the answer quite too much. Could you consider answering the question with your ideas? I'd upvote that!